# Kohana 3 URL::base method returns bad URL on HTTPS

Tags: php, kohana

I'm on Kohana 3.2 and I need to deploy the same application to an HTTP server and a HTTPS server. In the head of my HTML I have my always loved:

```
<base href="<? echo URL::base(TRUE) ?>">
```

That's one of the best things I discovered for my views. The problem is that this is the first time I'm deploying to a HTTPS and it returns the wrong URL. This is the URL I request: https://s37839.gridserver.com/external/discovery/fbtabs/tlc_y_curiosidad/index.php/app/320141391342439

This is what URL::base(TRUE) returns: `http://s37839.gridserver.com:443/external/discovery/fbtabs/tlc_y_curiosidad/` (Note the "http://" and the 443 port.)
With this, the page doesn't load the assets correctly. You can check the page source for yourself.

I hope it's clear. Please let me know. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

It was a [bug in Kohana](http://dev.kohanaframework.org/issues/4135). They fixed it for the next release (3.3?). For now I got the new base() method from their [GitHub repo](https://github.com/kohana/core/blob/3.2/master/classes/kohana/url.php).

Answer (score 0):

Try using a [protocol relative url](http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/).

Comment: The problem is that even if I remove the scheme (what's before double slashes), Kohana's URL::base() is adding the 443 port into the URL, and that's not the request I need. Thanks anyway.